# Can I add my own books to Kindle for PC and have them sync with my Andoid phone?

Tags: android, kindle

I don't own a Kindle, but I still use the app for reading on both my PC and Android phone (Samsung Galaxy Note). Now I searched around and read that if I convert any book to mobi with calibre I should be able to open it in Kindle for PC and it does, but then it doesn't show up on my phone. Is this normal or am I doing something wrong?

I am adding the converted book by drag-n-drop to Kindle for PC

Answer (score 0):

Amazon only syncs purchases and files sent through the Amazon service. It pushes them down to your Kindle software on various platforms. The kindle software on your PC does not push files up to Amazon or other devices.

You can email personal documents to your Kindle. From [Amazon support](http://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html/ref=hp_navbox_email_200375630?nodeId=200375630&#email):

> With Kindle Personal Documents Service, you can send your personal
>   documents to your registered Kindle devices, supported Kindle reading
>   applications, and your Kindle Library in the Amazon Cloud through the
>   Send to Kindle application or your Send-to-Kindle e-mail address.

There is a fee for this service:

> Fees for the Kindle Personal Documents Service via Whispernet are
>   based on the size of the file submitted (before compression if you use
>   a .zip file), your country, and where you're accessing Whispernet.
>   Personal documents service fees will only be charged for documents
>   that are successfully delivered to your Kindle device via Whispernet.
>   Personal documents service fees are rounded up to the next whole MB
>   and apply to each personal document delivered via Whispernet to each
>   Kindle device.

Comment: I see. Is there a way to replicate the syncing function of Kindle for books not bought from amazon?

Comment: Updated answer with link to Amazon support page about document service

Comment: @IntelligentStupidity - Any solution that exists would not work with the Kindle software.

Answer (score 0):

You can send web pages and personal documents to your Amazon account, and read them on any registered device, including Kindle for PC. As long add you don't use whispernet for the download the is no charge.

I've sent all three kinds to my Kindle before, including books from a third party web site.

The Amazon send-to-Kindle browser plugin is really useful for reading pages offline.